# Schedule a setTimeout within a setInterval

Tags: javascript, timer, settimeout, setinterval

I have a program in javascript that executes a sentence generated with blockly
This is generated as follows:

I have a setInterval that causes this code to be repeated every second, and within this code is the function that generates blockly. This code can contain one or more setTimeout. If the setTimeout lasts more than 1 second that the setInterval lasts, I break the loop, since the setInterval does not wait for that time to pass, it is executed again. Is there any way to solve this?

```
setInterval(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
       console.log("Hola")
    }, 5000)
}, 1000);
```

Why the console.log runs every second?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you actually want.

Perhaps this? An attempt to start a timeout every 5 seconds but only if there is not one already

```js
var tId;
setInterval(function() {
  if (!tId) tId = setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("Hola", tId, new Date());
    tId = "";
  }, 5000)
}, 1000);
```